# Print SSRSReport to file (.PDF)

Tags: pdf, printing, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I need to find a way to "print" a `SrsReport`, in my case `SalesInvoice`, as .PDF (or any kind of file) to a specific location.

For this I modified the `SRSPrintDestinationSettings` to output the SalesInvoice-Report as a .PDF:

```
settings = controller.parmReportContract().parmPrintSettings();
settings.printMediumType(SRSPrintMediumType::File);
settings.fileFormat(SRSReportFileFormat::PDF);
settings.overwriteFile(true);
settings.fileName(@'\\AXDEV\Bottomline\Test\test.pdf');
```

Somehow this gets ignored and I recive a Email with the report as .PDF attached.

For example this will run on ax 2012 but won't print to PDF for me.

```
SRSPrintDestinationSettings     settings;
CustInvoiceJour         custInvoiceJour;
SrsReportRunController          controller = new SrsReportRunController();
PurchPurchaseOrderContract  rdpContract = new PurchPurchaseOrderContract();
SalesInvoiceContract    salesInvoiceContract = new SalesInvoiceContract();

select firstOnly1 * from custInvoiceJour where custInvoiceJour.SalesId != "";

// Define report and report design to use
controller.parmReportName(ssrsReportStr(SalesInvoice,Report));
// Use execution mode appropriate to your situation
controller.parmExecutionMode(SysOperationExecutionMode::Synchronous);


rdpContract.parmRecordId(custInvoiceJour.RecId);
controller.parmReportContract().parmRdpContract(rdpContract);

// Explicitly provide all required parameters
salesInvoiceContract.parmRecordId(custInvoiceJour.RecId); // Record id must be passed otherwise the report will be empty
controller.parmReportContract().parmRdpContract(salesInvoiceContract);
salesInvoiceContract.parmCountryRegionISOCode(SysCountryRegionCode::countryInfo()); // comment this code if tested in pre release

// Change print settings as needed
settings = controller.parmReportContract().parmPrintSettings();
settings.printMediumType(SRSPrintMediumType::File);
settings.fileFormat(SRSReportFileFormat::PDF);
settings.overwriteFile(true);
settings.fileName(@'\\AXDEV\Bottomline\Test\test.pdf');

//tokens = settings as SrsPrintDestinationTokens();
//controller.parmPrintDestinationTokens(null);

//Suppress report dialog
controller.parmShowDialog(false);
// Execute the report
controller.startOperation();
```

Questions:
Is this the correct way to print a srsReport to .pdf?
Am I passing/setting the printerSettings correctly?
Where does it say "Send Email"?

EDIT: Code is working fine. We are using external code of a company which simply doesnt implement this.
Use the cleaner code of Alex Kwitny

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is working code for me.  I just quickly coded this from scratch/memory based off of glancing at yours, so compare for differences.

I have two things marked (1) and (2) for you to try with your code, or just copy/paste mine.

```
static void JobSendToPDFInvoice(Args _args)
{
    SrsReportRunController          controller = new SrsReportRunController();
    SRSPrintDestinationSettings     settings;
    CustInvoiceJour                 custInvoiceJour = CustInvoiceJour::findRecId(5637925275);
    SalesInvoiceContract            salesInvoiceContract = new SalesInvoiceContract();
    Args                            args = new Args();

    controller.parmReportName(ssrsReportStr(SalesInvoice, Report));
    controller.parmExecutionMode(SysOperationExecutionMode::Synchronous);
    controller.parmShowDialog(false);

    salesInvoiceContract.parmRecordId(custInvoiceJour.RecId);
    salesInvoiceContract.parmDocumentTitle(CustInvoiceJour.InvoiceId);
    salesInvoiceContract.parmCountryRegionISOCode(SysCountryRegionCode::countryInfo());

    // (1) Try by passing args
    args.record(custInvoiceJour);
    args.parmEnum(PrintCopyOriginal::Original);
    args.parmEnumType(enumNum(PrintCopyOriginal));

    controller.parmReportContract().parmRdpContract(salesInvoiceContract);    
    controller.parmArgs(args);

    // (2) Try explicitly preventing loading from last value
    // controller.parmLoadFromSysLastValue(false);

    // Change print settings as needed
    settings = controller.parmReportContract().parmPrintSettings();
    settings.printMediumType(SRSPrintMediumType::File);
    settings.fileFormat(SRSReportFileFormat::PDF);
    settings.overwriteFile(true);
    settings.fileName(@'C:\Temp\Invoice.pdf');


    controller.startOperation();
}
```

Comment: The code does the same as mine, but better :D . The code should work fine for everybody else out there. The problem is that my company uses a technologie from the company called Bottomline. It looks like it doesnt support PDF-output yet. I will have to modify it. Thanks for ur help =)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about the sales invoice the report is using the print management feature and you cannot simply override the print settings like that.

You need to override the `runPrintMgmt` on the controller class and determine there whether you want default print management or your own code.

See this post for an example: [http://www.winfosoft.com/blog/microsoft-dynamics-ax/manipulating-printer-settings-with-x](https://axfactory.wordpress.com/tag/x-ssrs-reports-print-management/)

Comment: Aww no. So I realy need to override it. I though I could bypass this ;/. Well thanks for the link. Gonna try it as soon as I can.

Comment: I do not believe you need to do this, see my answer below.  He's using `SrsReportRunController`, not `SrsPrintMgmtController`